# Word boundary matching empty strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently trying to get a match on an empty string in PHP, this current run through should match `not` and empty `''` but I can only seem to get it to match `not` for some reason? Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
preg_match('/^\bnot|$/', 'not', $matches);
print_r($matches);  // array(0 => 'not') // correct

preg_match('/^\bnot|$/', '', $matches);
print_r($matches);  // array(0 => '') // maybe right ?

preg_match('/^\bnot|$/', 'foo', $matches);
print_r($matches);  // array(0 => '') // deff messed up
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match here? A word boundary following the start of your subject is superfluous; why not just `if ($str == 'not')` ? Or should the string start with `not`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are trying to match an empty string incorrectly. Your regular expression should be.

```
^$|pattern
```

And with `\b` (word boundary), this matches from a `\w` (word character) to a `\W` (non word character). It is in fact a zero-width match (empty string) but only matches those strings at specific places in a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if a string is empty, don't use preg_match. Use strlen();

```
$string = '';
$strlen = strlen($string);
if ($strlen === 0) {
    // $string is empty
}
```